# Magento2 restore quote when click on browser back button from payment page

Tags: button, back

When i place order from magento2 website and goes to payment page when i click on back button of browser from payment page and redirect to magento2 webiste carts get empty i need to restore the item in cart for when I click on back button of browser from payment page

Comment: any idea......?

Answer (score 2):

When you clicked the place order button, that order was placed and quote was removed.

Here's the solution. Create an observer for the event *controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index* on the checkout page

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index">
        <observer name="initiate_checkout_onepage" instance="YourObserverClass" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then, on *YourObserverClass*, get last order base on checkout session and restore last quote like this:

```
    private $checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\Proxy $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $lastRealOrder = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        if ($lastRealOrder->getPayment()) {

            if ($lastRealOrder->getData('state') === 'new' && $lastRealOrder->getData('status') === 'pending') {
                $this->checkoutSession->restoreQuote();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```